# Python strings formatting

Tags: python, string

Given a string containing at least one space character.
Output the substring located between the first and second spaces of the source string. If the string contains only one space, then output an empty string.
My attempt:
But input is incorrect, for example: user_input=Hello World my name ,   input is: World my , i don't know why , can you help me?

```
user_input = input("Enter your string: ")


space_counter = 0
for char in user_input:
    if char == " ":
        space_counter += 1

if space_counter > 1:
    start_space_index = None
    for i in range(len(user_input)):
        if user_input[i] == " ":
            start_space_index = i
            break

    second_space_index = None
    for i in range(len(user_input)-1, -1, -1):
        if user_input[i] == " ":
            second_space_index = i
            break

    print(user_input[start_space_index+1: second_space_index])
else:  
    print("Empty string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: 1

Assuming the input like:

```
hello my name is abc
```

Output should be

```
hello my
```

Example 2:

input

```
hello my
```

output

```
None
```

Code:

```
a = 'hello my name is abc'
obj = a.split(" ") #this splits like ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is',   'abc']
if len(obj) > 2:
    print(obj[0], obj[1])
else:
    print None
```

Comment: sorry, can you do it with my code

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is

```
    user_input = input("Enter your string: ")
    Lst = user_input.split(" ")

    space_counter = 0
    for char in user_input:
        if char == " ":
        space_counter += 1

    if space_counter > 1:
       start_space_index = None
       for i in range(len(user_input)):
           if user_input[i] == " ":
              start_space_index = i
              break

       second_space_index = None
       for i in range(len(user_input)-1, -1, -1):
           if user_input[i] == " ":
              second_space_index = i
              break

       if user_input[0] == " ":
          print(Lst[0])
       else:  
          print(Lst[1])
```

Comment: nope,  Enter your string: aaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc dddddd
output: bbbbbbbb cccccc

Comment: ooh i can't solve this task, can you help me?

Comment: yes, for sure. i have edited the above answer kindly check it.

Comment: but yet it is not working for the output empty string.